# how to make a "add var per second" in js

Tags: javascript

so i was creating a html clicker game and im trying to create a "gain coins per second"
and an upgrade menu for that.

and also a autosave using js.

i tried using "return coins+cps;" but it said illegal return statement

and i also tried putting the return into a function but nothing happened

my code:

```
<div id="coin"><h3>title: <span id=title>newcomer</span>
  <h2> coins: 
    <code id="coins">1
    </code> 
  </h2>
  <img src="https://st3.depositphotos.com/3027583/16082/v/950/depositphotos_160820424-stock-illustration-pixel-art-golden-coin-retro.jpg?forcejpeg=true" width="50" height="50" onclick="addc(cpc)">
</div> 
<div id="upgrade"> 
  <div id="morecoins"> Coins Lv 
    <span id="level">1</span> 
    <br> Cost:<span id="cost">4</span><br>
    <button class="upgbtn" onclick="upgrade()">Upgrade
    </button>
  </s>
</div>
</div>
</div> 
<div id="upgrade"> 
  <div id="cps"> Coins Lv 
    <span id="level2">1</span> 
    <br> Cost:<span id="cost2">20</span><br>
    <button class="upgbtn" onclick="upgrade2()">Upgrade
    </button>
  </s>
</div>
</div>
<script src="scripts.js"></script>
<br>
V1.5
```

js:

```
var coins = 1;
var cpc = 1;
var lv = 1;

function addc(x) {
  coins += x;
  var coinshtml = (document.getElementById("coins").innerHTML = `${coins}`);
}

function removec(x) {
  coins -= x;
  var coinsnewnew = (document.getElementById("coins").innerHTML = `${coins}`);
}

function newlv() {
  lv += 1;
  cpc +=24;
document.getElementById("cost").innerHTML = `${cpc/5}`;
  document.getElementById("level").innerHTML = `${lv}`;
}
function upgrade() {
  removec(cpc/5)
  newlv()
  gg()
}
let lv2 = 1;
let cps=0;

function newlv2() {
  lv2 += 1;
  cps +=0.01;
document.getElementById("cost").innerHTML = `${cpc/2}`;
  document.getElementById("level").innerHTML = `${lv}`;
}
function upgrade2() {
  removec(cpc/2)
  newlv2()
}
```

css:

```
#coin {
  text-align: center;
}
.upgbtn {
  padding: 4px 16px;
  border: solid black 3px;
  background: green;
  border-radius: 12px;
}
#morecoins {
  padding: 8px 12px;
  border: solid black 3px;
  background: yellowgreen;
  border-radius: 12px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setInterval) which will execute a function indefinitely after a specified interval. It will return a number which is a handle you can use to stop the interval again using [`clearInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/clearInterval).

Here a quick demo which shows how you could implement such functionality:

```js
class Game{
  constructor(coinsPerInterval, intervalInMs){
    this.coins = 0;
    this.coinsPerInterval = coinsPerInterval;
    this.intervalInMs = intervalInMs;
  }

  start(){
    this.intervalHandle = setInterval(() => {
      this.coins += this.coinsPerInterval;
      console.log(`Coins: ${this.coins}`);
    }, this.intervalInMs);
  }

  stop(){
    clearInterval(this.intervalHandle);
  }
}

// 10 coins every second
const game = new Game(10, 1000);
game.start();
// stop the game after 5-15 seconds for demo purposes
setTimeout(() => game.stop(), Math.floor(10000 * Math.random() + 5000));
```

Comment: i used to use this but its too complex for me

Comment: i cant edit it today. ill need to change a lot of things in the code